# How to break up a string into a vector fast?

Tags: c++, string, performance, csv, stringstream

I am processing CSV and using the following code to process a single line.

[play with code](https://godbolt.org/z/zhj5a5)

```
std::vector<std::string> string_to_vector(const std::string& s, const char delimiter, const char escape) {
  std::stringstream sstr{s};
  std::vector<std::string> result;
  while (sstr.good()) {
    std::string substr;
    getline(sstr, substr, delimiter);
    while (substr.back() == escape) {
      std::string tmp;
      getline(sstr, tmp, delimiter);
      substr += "," + tmp;
    }
    result.emplace_back(substr);
  }
  return result;
}
```

**What it does:** Function breaks up string `s` based on `delimiter`. If the delimiter is escaped with `escape` the delimiter will be ignored.

This code works but is super slow. **How can I speed it up?**

Do you know any existing csv processing implementation that does exactly this and which I could use?

Comment: FWIW, You should move `getline(sstr, substr, delimiter)` into the while condition instead of using `sstr.good()`.  You should always use the read operation to control reading loops.  More at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: `while (sstr.good())` is not so good.

Comment: You can `move` the `substr` into the results vector

Comment: You could eliminate the usage of `stringstream` and use the `string::find` and `string::substr` methods.  Looks like an extra copy or duplicate effort when using `std::stringstream`.

Comment: "How can I speed it up?" - Compile your code with compiler optimizations *enabled* is the obvious first suggestion (note: that's usually not the default when you build your code, you need to take explicit steps to do so).

Comment: @NathanOliver and Waqar: Okay. Did this. Thank you for the advice

Comment: @Waqar How should I move the substr in the result vector?

Comment: `result.emplace_back(std::move(substr));`

Comment: @john totally agree! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way to do something is to not do it at all.

If you can ensure that your source string `s` will outlive the use of the returned vector, you could replace your `std::vector<std::string>` with `std::vector<char*>` which would point to the beginning of each substring. You then replace your identified delimiters with zeroes.

[EDIT] I have not moved up to C++17, so no `string_view` for me :)

NOTE: typical CSV is different from what you imply; it doesn't use escape for the comma, but surrounds entries with comma in it with double quotes. But I assume you know your data.

Implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<char*> string_to_vector(std::string& s, 
                                    const char delimiter, const char escape) 
{
  size_t prev(0), pos(0), from(0);
  std::vector<char*> v;
  while ((pos = s.find(delimiter, from)) != s.npos)
  {
    if (pos == 0 || s[pos - 1] != escape)
    {
      s[pos] = 0;
      v.push_back(&s[prev]);
      prev = pos + 1;
    }
    from = pos + 1;
  }
  v.push_back(&s[prev]);
  return v;
}

int main() {
  std::string test("this,is,a\\,test");
  std::vector<char*> v = string_to_vector(test, ',', '\\');

  for (auto& s : v)
    std::cout << s << " ";
}
```

Comment: Even more C++: Use std::string_view instead of char*.

Comment: Could you guys provide the full example. AFAIK string_views are just `char*` with a size attribute. So both should be fine

Comment: With string_view, there is no need to modify the original character storage.

Comment: The problem with `char*` and `std::string_view` is the allocation/storage policy: how data is allocated and who is the ownership? Returning a `std::vector<std::string_view>` or a `std::vector<char*>` seems great at first glance, but it is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that all `std::string_view`/`char*` does not outlive the pointed-to character array. Since to the delimiter not being always a "," in this implementation (see the concatenation), new data has to be allocated and stored somewhere as long as the vector is used.

Comment: I think I might be able to do that @JérômeRichard. Could you provide me with a working example?

Comment: @JérômeRichard it wouldn't be hard to make a class that makes its own copy of the string to ensure it remains valid, then provides `operator[]` to make it look like a `vector`.  You could even provide `begin()` and `end()` that return a `vector<char*>::iterator` using the private `vector<char*>` contained within the object.

Comment: @MarkRansom - that would be an elegant solution. In my defense, the OP did ask for "fast" and tagged this with `performance`... :)

Comment: @MarkRansom Sure, but the resulting type would be quite different from the original requirement (which may not be a requirement). I mainly wanted to point out that the big string to create is far from being free. I am wondering if this would be much faster than adding custom allocator for strings, avoiding copies with `std::move` and parsing the string with something faster than `std:stringstream` (based on the original code). This being said, this is an interesting approach!